# OpenGL ES 2 - noob question regarding depth

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

okay i'm kind of new to this 3D math and it was a major milestone was to get the projection & modelview matrices right last night :]

so i've got this simple model which renders correctly from this angle:

[image]

but when i rotate around the y axis, there's something wrong with the depth like this:

[image]

that might look interesting, but is not what i want currently. Basically the depth of these walls get mixed up?

can someone point me to the necessary steps on how to solve this? i need a depth buffer or something... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable depth testing by calling

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

And of course do not forget to clear your buffers by calling:

```
glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I hope that this will help ;)

Comment: Yes i'm doing that and it does do a proper depth test from one side of the object, but mixes it up from the other side . Guess there's something wrong with my modelView/projection setup. It probably does the depth test before rotating the object, or something.... Will post some code once I get back home..

Comment: In the most beginning you have to enable depth test and clear your buffers before drawing anything. And also double check if you drawn your cube correctly.

Comment: i'm doing that. i am positive that i'm drawing the cube correctly. Backface Culling works.. i'm sure the problem is with the projection matrix stuff..

Comment: Ah nice. Your comment about doing the depth test before draw helped me in my issue. Amusingly enough, it was an Android issue